# jQuery event to validate input in real time

Tags: jquery

I have a form field that I would like to validate.

```
<label for="name">Name: </label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"></input>
```

I want to do an AJAX request when the user fills the input and moves to the next input.

What event am I supposed to listen with jQuery?

I know jQuery Validation Plugin, but I think its too killer for such simple callback.

Comment: Listen for the `change` event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each of your inputs you can listen for the `blur` event. [**Test it out here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/AgPp4/1/)

**HTML**

```
<form id='myform'>
    <label for="fname">First Name: </label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"></input>
    <br/>
    <label for="lname">Last Name: </label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"></input>
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#myform').children('input').each(function(i, input){
    $(input).on('blur', validator);
});

function validator(){
    console.log('validating code goes here');
}
```